# Apply multiple imputation to non-random missing data

Tags: logistic, missing-data, multiple-imputation, mice

I am working on a multi-center project (3 centers; recruit ~20 participants in each center with a total of 60 participants). One of my independent variables (depression scale; continuous variable) was completely not documented in one of the centers.

My question is: when dealing with this non-random missingness, do multiple imputations (MICE package in R) still work when it comes to logistic/linear regression or should I exclude these 20 participants when analyzing this variable?

Answer (score 1):

MICE will do a reasonably good job on recovery of missing information, especially for chained regression methods.   But recall, you should report both results for (a) MICE under a table row title like "imputation of missing results," and then (b) results when missing are dropped from analyses in a row entitled e.g. "missing are dropped."  Additionally, national review groups often expect a plot of p-values or regression coefficients (Z-scores) as a function of "varying levels of missingness."

For varying levels of missingness analysis, think about creating a new variable called e.g. "missprob."  Next, for non-missing outcomes assign a 0 to missprob.  Then, for records with missing, randomly assign numbers in range [0,1] to the variable missprob.  Then, gradually ramp up a criterion threshold of e.g. $t=0.05, 0.1, 0.2., 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 0.95,$ and at each ramped up value of $t$ accept records for the regression whose missprob$\leq t$.  Repeat this procedure e.g. 500 times, that is,

1. assign new random variates again to the "missprob" variable for
   records with missing
2. Perform regression analysis at each level of $t$, each time accepting records with missing if missprob$\leq t$.
3. Perform bookkeeping of the p-values for the depression scale or
   treatment variable during each regression run for each value of $t$

After the above iterations, plot p-values as a function of $t$.